# Android id error

Tags: android

I am new to android and having this same problem every time I do something. Whenever I put a line this line in any of my codes it gives me an error in "id". The error says, "id cannot be resolved or is not a field."

What am I doing wrong?

```
myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

Comment: Please accept some answers on your previous questions. Thats how the community works. Also, have you imported the R file of your application? You will find it in the gen-folder.

Answer (score 0):

The build is probably wrong.  Try cleaning.

In Eclipse:

`Project->Clean...`

Aso, make sure the `R` is referring too your `R` and not the Android `R`.